# What norms can be "universally" defined on any real vector space with a fixed basis?

Tags: ct.category-theory, linear-algebra, norms

Let $V$ be a real vector space and let $B = (b_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a basis. So every $v \in V$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination
$$ v = c_{\lambda_1} b_{\lambda_1} + c_{\lambda_2} b_{\lambda_2} + \cdots + c_{\lambda_n} b_{\lambda_n}$$
for some finite set of indices $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots, \lambda_n$ and real coefficients $c_{\lambda_1}, c_{\lambda_2}, \cdots, c_{\lambda_n}$.

We can easily define several norms on $V$. For example, having fixed an algebraic basis, we may define the $\ell^p$ norms on $V$:

$$ \|v\|_p = \sqrt[p]{ |c_{\lambda_1}|^p + |c_{\lambda_2}|^p + \cdots + |c_{\lambda_n}|^p }, \quad 1 \leq p < \infty$$
$$ \|v\|_\infty = \max\{ |c_{\lambda_1}|, |c_{\lambda_2}|, \cdots, |c_{\lambda_n}| \}$$

*Notably, I am not implying a priori that the resulting space has anything to do with sequence spaces or any generalization thereof, though it may look like that on the surface.*

These norms do not involve any structure except that we have some vector space and some basis. In a manner that I do not know how to formalize, there seems to be a certain "universality" to these constructions. For example, we can define these norms as the index set $\Lambda$ might be any member of the class of sets.

**Questions**

- Has it been formalized what norms are always defined on a vector space after a choice of any basis? For example, *weighted* $\ell^p$ norms are no such candidate since choosing the weights generally involve additional knowledge such as the cardinality of the basis. I presume there is a categorial formalization.
- If so, is there a comprehensive classification of such norms?

Comment: Your choice of basis $B$ gives you a linear isomorphism of $V$ with the vector space $c_{00}(\Lambda)$, i.e. the space of finitely supported functions from $\Lambda$ to $\mathbb{R}$, or equivalently the space of "sequences" indexed by $\Lambda$ in which only finitely many terms are nonzero.  So this seems equivalent to asking about norms on $c_{00}(\Lambda)$ for arbitrary sets $\Lambda$, and your two examples are the usual $\ell^p$ and $\ell^\infty$ norms on this space (with respect to counting measure, if you like).

Answer (score 8):

What you call the "usual $\ell^p$ norm on $V$" is anything but when $V$ is infinite-dimensional. For example when $p=2$, your norm is (as in the standard setting) induced by the scalar product $\langle v,w\rangle = \sum c_{\lambda}d_{\lambda}$, with $v=\sum c_{\lambda} b_{\lambda}$ and $w=\sum d_{\lambda}b_{\lambda}$.

Now if $V=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, then algebraic bases $B=\{ b_{\lambda} \}$ of $V$ are uncountable, so you obtain uncountably many mutually orthogonal vectors, and you certainly didn't put the standard norm on $V$.

Or, to say roughly the same thing more directly, if you start out with the standard vectors $e_n$, then you don't compute the norm of $v=\sum e_n/n$ as $\|v\|^2=\sum 1/n^2$. Rather, you first add (uncountably many) new vectors to $\{ e_n\}$ to obtain an algebraic basis, and then you expand $v$ in terms of these vectors.

Comment: What you actually do in this example is make $V=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ an incomplete space, with completion $\ell^2(\Lambda)$, if $\Lambda$ denotes an index set of a basis.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say, but I am not implying that $V$ with the norm in my post resembles any canonical space $\ell^p(\Lambda)$ (sequence space if $\Lambda$ is countable). However, I will improve the language of the post to avoid such confusion.

Comment: To emphasize one point here: in your post you refer to *the $\ell^p$ norms on $V$*... but that usage is incorrect, those norms you describe are not *the $\ell^p$ norms on $V$*.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking is this. You want a function $f:\mathbb R_0^{\Lambda}\to [0,\infty)$ where $\mathbb R_0^\Lambda$ is all $\Lambda$ tuples that are $0$ in all but finitely many places. You want $f$ to be subadditive, with $f(x)=0$ iff $x=0$, symmetric and independent of sign change.

There are plenty of such examples.

For example, if $\Lambda$ is finite, just take any subadditive function $g:\mathbb R^n\to [0,\infty)$, with $f(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ then define $h(x_1,...,x_n)=g(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)$. Then take the symmetrization.

If $\Lambda$ is $\mathbb N$ you can take the infinite symmetrization as a limit if $f$ satisfies some boundedness condition.

Every norm satisfying your condition comes from a procedure like this (namely, symmetrization of itself).

Comment: Your third paragraph has $f$, $g$, and $h$. Do they all have the meaning that you intended?

Comment: Thank you. But I am specifically interested in the case where I do not know the cardinality of $\Lambda$. Obviously, if $\Lambda$ over the entire class of sets, that's a very big number of constraints...